# Navigation Drawer Sequence

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

So I have a navigation drawer which has a home fragment. Inside the home fragment I have tabs inside. So in one of my tabs (Get Info). If I click a button inside the get info tab, I want it to go to my Fragment (Info), which is actually a item inside my navigation drawer. So how can this happen?

Any help with this will be deeply appreciated. Thank you very much.

```
public class HomePageActivity extends FragmentActivity
 {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);
            // Add items to the ListView
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new DrawerListAdapter(this,mDrawerItems,imageId));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        // Set the default content area to item 0
        // when the app opens for the first time
        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            navigateTo(0);
        }

    }


    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            navigateTo(position);
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerItems[position]);
            getActionBar().setIcon(imageId[position]);
        }
    }

    private void navigateTo(int position) {

        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame, homeFragment, HomeFragment.TAG).commit();
                break;
            case 1: //TODO
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame, GetInfo.newInstance()).commit();
                break;

             DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        ParseUser.getCurrentUser().logOut();
                        finish();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
                break;
        }
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
}
```

As you can see I have a tab inside my navigation drawer called GetInfo, which contains a button called GotoSettings. When I click on GoToSettings. I want it to go a item which is in my navigation drawer. Just like how I have these different cases, settings is one of those cases.

Comment: Would you kindly provide some code to ease our understanding?

Comment: @RodolfoPerottoni, I provided some sample code.